# How do I add values to a JSON object converted set as a cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, json, cookies, associative-array

I am trying to get an every increasing set of values into an associative array that is converted to json and then to a cookie.  I used the `rand` and `date` to make sure I was using unique values and not simply overwriting myself.

I have this,

```
$var = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$var2 = rand(5, 15);
$toCookie = array();
$toCookie[] = array($var2 => $var, "hash"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$json = json_encode($toCookie);
setcookie('recentviews', $json, time()+3600);


$cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["recentviews"], true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($cookie);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

How do I make that keep adding values to itself? I only have one value for $cookie.  I thought if I used `[]` the array would keep adding values to itself.

EDIT:  I think I have the answer, but I want to wait before I answer myself.  I used this:

```
$var = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$var2 = rand(5, 15);
$toCookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["recentviews"], true); //addition
$toCookie[] = array($var2 => $var, "hash"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$json = json_encode($toCookie);
setcookie('recentviews', $json, time()+3600);


$cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE["recentviews"], true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($cookie);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

In other words, I decoded first, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. Just one point: array isn't associative, it's a indexed array :-)  ($toCookie)